# Escape string using Struts2 tags

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I am trying to escape characters

```xml
<s:select list="#{'Achat d'eclair':'Achat d'eclair'}" />
```

How can I escape `Achat d'eclair` in Struts2 tags ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all with `#{}` notation you're creating a map where value before `:` is a key and after is a value and you probably don't want that the key of your map would be with some *complex* characters in it.

To escape `'` use `\\` like so:

```
<s:select list="#{'achatdeclair':'Achat d\\'eclair'}" />
```

Comment: I have used <s:select list="#{'achatd\\'eclair':'Achat d\\'eclair'}" /> and this works for me